# Android Google Fit select max results

Tags: android, google-fit

I try to develop some fitness application which will use Google Fit.
And i have one question. Assume that user make some sport activity a few days in a week. And want to show him his best result. The only way I know I can do this - is load all data from user history and then select the set with maximum value. 
And its obvious that I dont like that method because of the fact that I should load all the history. (And the user can have history for a few years).

Another way is to store data in local database (so i dont need to load all history every time the user want to see his best result) and synch it with google fit data, but I think its too dificult.

Do we have some other options for that kind of tasks?

Comment: Yeah, one time load the highest value, save it in cache, compare all new values. If new value is higher, replace it, else ignore. Save yourself from loading entire history. Its as simple as it can get.

Answer (score 0):

Use sharedpreferences to save the value,
To set value

```
SharedPreferences prefs = this.getSharedPreferences("myhighestscore", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
Editor editor = prefs.edit();
editor.putInt("key", score);
editor.commit();
```

To get value

```
SharedPreferences prefs = this.getSharedPreferences("myhighestscore", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
int score = prefs.getInt("key", 0);
```

here is a [link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html).

[Using Shared Preferences](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref)

Comment: The problem is that the user can have 2 mobile phones. If i will save the value localy on 1st mobile, then the second mobile will not be synchronized with the first.

Comment: Same principle applies, regardless, in this just change storage from local, to however you are planning to do. You can opt for persistent storage. The next question is data exchange format, xml or json. Also look into android syncadapter